# Creating controls in code behind and passing them to xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
public CONTROL selectedControl(string sControl)
{
    CONTROL result = new CONTROL();

    if(sContro.Equals("TextBox"))
    {
        TextBox txtBx = new TextBox();
        // custom TextBox
        result = txtBx;
    }
    else if(sControl.Equals("Button"))
    {
       ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

And how can I put that in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any `UIElement` to the `Children` property of a `Panel` that you define in your XAML markup.

Please refer to the following sample code.

**Code:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var child = selectedControl("TextBox");
        stackPanel.Children.Add(child);
    }

    public UIElement selectedControl(string sControl)
    {
        UIElement result = null;

        if (sControl.Equals("TextBox"))
        {
            TextBox txtBx = new TextBox();
            // custom TextBox
            result = txtBx;
        }
        //...
        return result;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you.. :)
can you tell me how to do it in term of MVVM?

Comment: You don't create controls anywhere else than in the view...maybe you should look up how ItemsControl work.